error CANON_EQ flag not supported in Android app
I'm trying to connect to a MariaDB database from an Android app. The connection is established, but I can’t execute a query to the database because I get an error "java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: CANON_EQ flag not supported"
when executing line statement = connection.createStatement();
...
import org.mariadb.jdbc.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import org.mariadb.jdbc.Statement;
...
Connection connection = null;
Statement statement = null;
...
connectButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final String url = "jdbc:mariadb://" + db_address + ":" + String.valueOf(db_port) +
                        "/" + db_name;
                try {
                    Class.forName("org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver");
                    connection = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(url, db_user, db_password);
                    tv_info.setText("Database connection established");
                    System.out.println("Database connection established");
                    statement = connection.createStatement();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println(e.getMessage() + " ///////////////////////////////");
                    tv_info.setText("Database connection not established");
                }
            }
        });

Please advise how to solve the problem.

Please read: JDBC vs Web Service for Android

Second to the above, + CANNON_EQ is part of the MariaDB JDBC driver. It does seem easy to fix baring using a very obsolete connector version.

As comments indicate, check JDBC vs Web Service for Android, as using JDBC directly is rarely the best solution. Still this CANNON_EQ has no reason to block use when using androind. https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/CONJ-1185 created. SNAPSHOT available :
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>sonatype-nexus-snapshots</id>
        <name>Sonatype Nexus Snapshots</name>
        <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mariadb.jdbc</groupId>
        <artifactId>mariadb-java-client</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>


As far as I understand, I should use mariadb-java-client-3.4.1.jar, but I did not find such a version anywhere. I solved this problem by using mariadb-java-client-1.8.0.jar instead of mariadb-java-client-3.4.0.jar

@YeS, Diego is the maintainer of Connector/J and created this snapshot for you after the 3.4.1 release.
